# ssh match condition: connect only via key only for a specif user and not on a specific subnet

Tags: linux, ssh

I want to be able to connect to an ssh server with an user only via key but only if he is not connecting from a specific subnet. If he is connecting from this specific subnet password authentication is valid too.
I used this match condition that I put at the end on my `sshd_config` file:

```
Match User my_user Address !10.*
  PasswordAuthentication no
Match all
```

But it doesn't work, I can still login via password even if my address is not 10.*

UPDATE:
Splitting the conditions in 2 Match seems to work but it's not possible to use a single Match?

```
 Match Address 10.*
     PasswordAuthentication yes
 Match User my_user
    PasswordAuthentication no
 Match all
```

Comment: You can verify your match blocks with calls like `sshd -T -C user=my_user,addr=10.0.01 | grep -i auth`

Comment: It returns `user, host and addr are all required when testing Match configs`,  what to put on host? I used `host *` and my condition doesn't work.